# to support iptv directly on udp/tcp

Tags: udp, rtp, live555

I used to suport live555 client on android. it was supposed use rtp over udp/tcp. now I was asked to run it directly on udp/tcp in single program. Frankly, without rtcp/rtp, how could udp frames be reordered?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to develop your own protocol. I'd suggest looking at how TFTP is implemented. Keep in mind however that with UDP datagrams, there are no guarantees; you will be responsible for ensuring out of order data is discarded and that lost/undelivered datagrams are handled/tolerated by your protocol.